# GoLang NewSingleHostReverseProxy is being cached in browser

Tags: go

I built a simple Reverse proxy in GoLang where it routes to a random server from a list of servers.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "math/rand"
  "net/http"
  "net/http/httputil"
  "net/url"
  "time"
)

func main() {

    servers := []string{"http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8080/a", "http://localhost:8080/b"}

    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        randomIndex := rand.Intn(len(servers))
        randomServer := servers[randomIndex]

        fmt.Printf("Chosen server: %v\n", randomServer)

        host, err := url.Parse(randomServer)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            return
        }
        proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(host)

        proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)

    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8082", nil)

}
```

I then built a simple webserver which exposes the routes `/`, `/a` and `/b` which runs on 8080.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("This is Route /"))
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/a", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("This is Route a"))
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/b", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("This is Route b"))
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Now, when I open `localhost:8082` on my browser, on each refresh, I should randomly be shown either `/` or `/a/` or `/b`, but I get `/` evertime. The print statement prints a random server everytime, so there's no issue in the random logic, but the browser always shows `/`

Even if I remove `localhot:8080` from the list of servers and reload the go project, it still opens `/`

Also incidentally, after closing my server on port `8082`, If i try `lsof -i:8082`, I get an instance of my Brave browser running something

[image]

I've attached a video of the entire issue here - https://youtu.be/kIET4QF7rSY

Somehow, the route is being cached even if it's not the first chosen route

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the backend server.

The proxy joins the target server path and the request path.  The result of joining the target path `/a` and request path `/` is `/a/`.

The incoming path `/a/` at the backend server does not match the mux pattern `/a`, but the path does match the pattern `/`.  The handler for `/` is invoked as a result. See the [ServeMux documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux) for more information on how the mux matches the incoming request path with registered patterns.

Fix by adding a trailing slash to the patterns for routes A and B:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("This is Route /"))
})

http.HandleFunc("/a/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("This is Route a"))
})

http.HandleFunc("/b/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("This is Route b"))
})
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the handler for / has to be registered last as well, else it will shadow the other two.

Comment: @Peter  The handlers can be registered in any order.  The mux calls the handler for the pattern that most closely matches the request path.